# Get available room with rates between arrival and departure date

Tags: mysql

Price plan master table

```
CREATE TABLE `price_plan_master` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id ( Auto Increment )',
  `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Room Id (Related to room_master table)',
  `date` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date to get rate',
  `no_of_rooms` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'No of rooms available',
  `rate` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'Room rate',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Id|room_id|date|no_of_rooms|rate
1|2|2017-10-01|5|8530
2|2|2017-10-02|5|8530
3|3|2017-10-01|5|8200
4|3|2017-10-02|5|8200
5|2|2017-10-01|2|14609
6|2|2017-10-02|2|14609
7|3|2017-10-03|2|14609
8|2|2017-10-04|2|14609
9|3|2017-10-01|2|13000
10|3|2017-10-02|2|13000
11|3|2017-10-03|2|13000
12|3|2017-10-04|2|13000
13|6|2017-10-01|3|17286
14|6|2017-10-02|3|17286
15|6|2017-10-03|3|17286
16|6|2017-10-04|3|17286
17|11|2017-10-01|10|2830
18|11|2017-10-02|10|2830
19|11|2017-10-03|10|2830
20|11|2017-10-04|10|2830
21|12|2017-10-01|2|1700
```

I want to fetch all rooms with conditions 
availability should be equals to or maximum requested no of rooms (means no_of_rooms >= 3) between requested check in and check out date.
For every date between date range room availability should be checked.

Currently, I am using below query.

```
select * from price_plan_master
where date >= checkin and date <= checkout
```

I need to check availability for all dates.

Can anyone suggest what should I change in single query to fetch records ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query you have written with an added AND condition:

```
 select * from price_plan_master
 where date >= checkin and date <= checkout
 and no_of_rooms >= 3
```

This will select all rooms in the date range where the number of rooms is greater than or equal to the requested number of rooms.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ppm.*
FROM price_plan_master ppm
INNER JOIN (
SELECT room_id, COUNT(room_id) AS cnt, DATEDIFF(checkout, checkin)+1 AS temp
FROM price_plan_master
WHERE `date` >= checkin AND `date` <= checkout AND no_of_rooms >= 3
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING cnt = temp) t ON ppm.room_id = t.room_id